# How to load a DLL in Iron python, written in c++ and wrapped in c#?

Tags: c#, c++, dll, ironpython, dllimport

I have a dll that was originally written in c++,
later a module in c# wrapped it and used this Import :

```
[DllImport("myDLL.dll", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern int init();
```

I'm now using Iron Python and want to use the functions in the original DLL that were imported in this c# program.

Basically I don't know what to import to python. when I had a simple project in c# that was converted into a dll I added it :

```
clr.AddReferenceToFileAndPath("my path")
```

then I imported the Namespace and all the function.

In this case I don't understand witch dll I should import ?
any help would be appriciated

edit:

this is what I'm doing:

```
 >>> import sys

  >>> import clr

 >>> clr.AddReferenceToFileAndPath(r"wrapperPath.dll")

>>> import wrapper

>>> from wrapper import *

>>> init()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'initialize' is not defined
```

Comment: What is the problem you are having?

Comment: I will edit it now to be more clear

Comment: Pretty hard to see how init() morphed into "initialize".  Avoid obfuscating code.

Answer (score 0):

C# does not have functions without classes.  Your problem is probably solved by ParentClassName.init().  It might be a better idea to have an instance method that does the call to the C++ P/Invoke signature for the purpose of debugging or logging.  Good luck.